# Select one option from each combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, combobox

I have 6 html selects on a form, each of which contains the same 8 options.

If an option has been chosen from one of the selects, then I'd like that option to be disabled  in all other selects. I'd like the option to still be visible (i.e. it must not be removed).

Is there a jquery plugin or similar that can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/jbjkm/3/

```
$.fn.exclusiveSelectSet = function() {
  var set = this, options = this.find('option');
  return this.change(function() {
    var selected = {};
    set.each(function(){ selected[this.value] = true });
    options.each(function() {
      var sel = this.parentNode;
      this.disabled = this.value && selected[this.value] &&
                      sel.options[sel.selectedIndex] != this;
    });
  }).change();
}

$('select.loves').exclusiveSelectSet();
$('#likes select').exclusiveSelectSet();
```

In English, whenever a select value is changed:

1. Find the `values` of all selected options.
2. Disable any option that has one of the selected values,
    unless it doesn't have any value (`value=""`) or it is the selected option in its `<select>`.

Comment: @JonoB You're welcome. Note the edit I just made that fixed a small bug. Previously when you selected an option on select #2 the selected value in select #1 would become disabled (even though it was selected).

Comment: The enabled/disabled state seems to be working well. However, I'm not quite sure what is going wrong here, but it seems like posted values from the selects are now going missing.

Comment: @JonoB You'll need to provide more details than that, preferably in the form of [a working example](http://jsfiddle.net) showing the problem. Did you put `name="..."` attributes on your `<select>`?

Comment: OK, ignore that - cleared the cache and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

to disable/enable all other checkboxes with the same value add this Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[tpye="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
      $('input[value="'.$(this).val().'"]').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
      });
    else
      $('input[value="'.$(this).val().'"]').each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
      });
  });
});
```

if u use selects try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').change(function(){
    $('option:disabled').each(function(){
      $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
    });
    $('select').each(function(){
      var v = $(this).val();
      $('option[value="'+v+'"]').each(function(){
        if($(this).parent() != $(this))
          $(this).attr('disabled',true);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

EDIT: ah, right, enable all option before disabling some (reset)

Comment: yeah right, i was commiting by error, thats a solution for checkboxes, will post the one for selects in a minute

Comment: The added part works for me, see [this snippet](http://jsbin.com/oyaluk/7/edit) on jsbin.